# What hash algorithm to use for quick file hashing?

Tags: c++, hash

What I'm looking for, as the title says, is for the best common hashing algorithm. It should be relatively quick to hash a 10mb or so file, and it should be as secure as possible to avoid collisions.

Also, a link to a C++ implementation would be appreciated, preferably one with a licence that allows it to be used in a free but closed-source application, and if possible, a paid, closed-source application.

Comment: CRC-32? Maybe Addler? How important is speed here, really?

Comment: There is never a *best* solution for a problem.

Comment: @Philipp There actually is, but it requires solving the halting problem. :P

Comment: Does the algorithm need to be cryptographically secure (can intentional hash collisions be used to sabotage your system)?

Comment: @Richard Depends on how fast these are, I've never used any hashing algorithm, so I have no idea what the speeds are.

Comment: @Philipp Yes, it could cause problems if intentional collisions are used.

Comment: What do you mean with "collisions should not be easy to get". When your hashes are less data than your input, there is always the chance for collisions. Which chance for an accidental collision between any given two inputs would be acceptable for your use case? One in thousand? One in a million? One in a billion? One in a trillion?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, 32 bits might not be sufficient if the goal is to eliminate the possibility of a hash collision. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table

Comment: For my case, 1 in a million would be sufficient. My problem though isn't the chance of accidental collisions, it's more the chance of intentional collisions...

Comment: @nicotranquil: Even though yzt's answer is correct in all aspects, if you want to avoid *intentional* collisions then you should avoid using MD5 or SHA-1 since there are known collision attacks on these algorithms (MD5 is even trivial to break, takes a few seconds on a modern computer). SHA-256 or SHA-512 will do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that when hashing files, your bottleneck is most likely to be file I/O and not the hashing algorithm itself. Obviously, this observation holds unless you select a *very* slow hash algorithm (I know of none in mainstream use that are that slow) or your hardware is very unusual and peculiar.

To give you some (very inaccurate) numbers, most good implementations of cryptographic hash algorithms (which are probably much stronger than you need) run at many hundreds of megabytes or a couple of gigabytes per second, but most common disk systems run at tens of megabytes or a couple of hundred megabytes per second.

Note that in these (very rough) numbers, I'm ignoring the overhead of filesystem and OS, and also I'm assuming that you'll use a cryptographic hash algorithm (which are typically slower than simpler ones.)

All in all, my advice is that you just pick something like MD5 or SHA-1 or SHA-256 (these are all cryptographic hashes) which have a lot of good, fast and free implementations and practically remove any chance of collisions. And instead of picking a fast but inferior hash algorithm, optimize your I/O (by doing asynchronous/non-blocking reading of your files) because that's where the bottleneck is going to be.

Here are just a few crypto libraries for C/C++ that implement various hash functions, and have licenses suitable for your use case:

1. [Crypto++](http://cryptopp.com/)
2. [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/)
3. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/)

Comment: Concentrating on the overheads of the file IO is a good suggestion. Mem-mapping is a good thing to look into too to solve this.

Comment: @Will: Certainly memory-mapping the input files can help, but I think for this particular use case (reading files sequentially and from start to finish,) using I/O tricks may yield faster results.

Comment: @Will: (in continuation of my last comment!) Oh, unless you map the file into memory, and start hashing from the beginning but systematically touch memory pages ahead to give to OS time to generate the page faults and load the content into memory! That's certainly easier to do than to mess with (e.g.) Windows overlapped I/O API or completion ports or spawning multiple threads to do I/O!

Comment: @Will I think in this case overlapping I/O will be even faster than memory mapping, since you already know you're going to need to read the entire file long before the OS will figure it out.

Comment: @MarkRansom, You are right. Overlapped IO is most likely going to be faster. However Memmapping may well be easier to implement and would provide some improvement in IO speed, especially if you do the trick that yzt suggests.

Comment: @Will, touching the pages ahead of time won't help unless you do it from a different thread - you'll just block otherwise. I certainly agree that memory mapping is the easiest way to get a performance boost though.